# Get selected value from ListView with bound XML file

Tags: wpf, xml, listview

I have a `ListView` control that shows data from a XML file. But the `ListView` has `GridView` child with two columns - icon and title. The idea is when I click on element to get the value only from the title column. Instead I get the entire XML node.

This is a theoretical question, but if you need code, I will provide it :)

thank you

update:

XML file:

```
<list>
<item>
<title>demo</title>
<icon>icon.png</icon>
</item>
<item>
<title>demo2</title>
<icon>icon2.png</icon>
</item>
</list>
```

XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="feed"
                         Source="http://feedurl/sites.xml"
                         XPath="list/item" />

        <DataTemplate x:Key="itemIcons">
            <Grid x:Name="ImageGrid">
                <Image Source="{Binding XPath=icon}" Width="40" Height="40"></Image>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

more XAML:

```
<ListView Name="myList" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyContainer}" 
                  SelectionChanged="clicked" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  Height="auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="240" 
                  BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource feed}}" 
                  SelectionMode="Single" Margin="1,36,1,1">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Style>
                    </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn x:Name="showIcon" CellTemplate="{StaticResource itemIcons}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn x:Name="showSites" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=title}" Header="some header"/>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

C#:

```
private void clicked(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var title= this.myList.SelectedValue.ToString();
            //MessageBox.Show(title);
        }
```

when I click on my `ListView` item, I get the title and the icon nodes concatenated, e.g. "demoicon.png" and I want only the "title" value :)

thanks in advance ;)